# adding items to an array in async call does not not update angular 1.5.8 view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Plunkr here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/aWBE55?p=preview

Let's say I have a view like this:

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myAppController as app" >
      <input type="text" ng-model="app.colorName" /><button ng-click="app.addColor()">add color</button>
      <div ng-repeat="c in app.colors">{{c.colorName}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and I have a controller like this:

```
var Color = function(options) {
  var self = this;
  self.colorName = options.colorName;
};

(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myAppController', function myAppController($filter) {
    var self = this;
    self.colorName = '';
    self.colors = [
      new Color({colorName: 'Red'}),
      new Color({colorName: 'Blue'}), 
      new Color({colorName: 'Green'})
      ];

    self.addColor = function() {
      console.log("added a new color " + self.colorName);
      self.colors.push(new Color({colorName: self.colorName}));
    };

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("added new color in another thread");
      self.colors.push(new Color({colorName: 'Purple'}));
        }, 1000);
    });
})(window.angular);
```

See that little setTimeout guy pushing another color onto the array? It seems that because it's being added from an async call (because of the setTimeout), the view does not refresh immediately and show the Purple color after it's been added.

Interestingly, even clicking into the textbox and then out (which touches that ng-model property) triggers a view update and 'Purple' appears... and, of course, adding a color by pushing the button refreshes the view immediately.

Why does this happen and what should I do about it?

I could do $scope.$apply, but that seems particularly hideous as the real world example (which involves modal dialogs with callbacks) is component-based and trying to get away from doing $scope-y things. This example was worked up for simplicity.

Comment: use `$timeout()` instead of `setTimeout()`. Angular has no way of knowing when a setTimeout is finished so it cannot update your bindings

Comment: btw the callback function from `setTimeout()` still runs in the same thread as the rest of your app

Comment: timeout's not the issue... that's just an example of a callback. The real world example isn't using setTImeout

Comment: if you run something asyncronous that Angular isn't aware of you need to manually trigger a digest. e.g. with `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: @BrettGreen didn't see these comments before posting my answer :(. @rob is right, but keep in mind if a `$scope.$apply()` is going to be applied is safer to be applied inside a `$timeout` in order to avoid a possible *$digest* error

Comment: I guess angular only does view updates when functions attached to the controller are completed? I expected it was watching the model and should just update but I guess it's not doing an observable approach like knockout?

Comment: Asynchronous APIs which use callbacks to return values should use the $q service to create promises that are integrated with the AngularJS framework. In the case of the setTimeout API, that work has already been done with the $timeout service,.